# Returning mysql_insert_id equivalent from Laravel's fluent query builder

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel's fluent query builder to insert a row into a table and want to get the newly inserted row's id. For instance, I would normally do something like:

```
public static function next_id() {
    $con = self::getInstance();
    return (int)mysqli_insert_id($con);
}
```

Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just flicked through \laravel\database\query.php and on line 820, there is a function called `insert_get_id($values, $column = 'id')` where the second parameter appears to return any column, but id by default!

Answer (score 0):

yup it's on the doc http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent - inserting record part

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = DB::table('table_name')->insertGetId(
array('email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0));   return $id;
```